# AttributeRouting - area with optional route parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

is it possible to have area with two routes. for example:

```
[RouteArea("{culture}/testarea")] <-- specific culture
[RouteArea("testarea")]  <-- default culture
LocalizableAreaBaseController ....
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this with a route constraint.

```
public class TestAreaAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "TestArea";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "TestArea_culture",
            "{culture}/TestArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { culture = @"^[A-Za-z]{2}(\-[A-Za-z]{2})$"}
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "TestArea_default",
            "TestArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Or

```
[RoutePrefix("{culture:regex(^[A-Za-z]{2}(\-[A-Za-z]{2})$)}/TestArea")]
[RoutePrefix("TestArea")]
public class TestController : ApiController {
}
```

(This particular regex constraint would match something like "en" or "en-gb")

Comment: Hi. thx for reply. but how will this work with AttributeRouting ?

Comment: I added an example using the ASP WebApi 2.0 RoutePrefix attribute.

Comment: but then culture parameter will be after area (testarea/en/...), and i'd like to have if before (/en/testarea/...)

Comment: A controller can't have more than one RoutePrefix: you will get an  "Duplicate 'RoutePrefix' attribute" error. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31053697/533460

Answer (score 1):

There is another prefix for that in RouteArea attribute please use that. That will works.

`[RouteArea("testarea"),AreaPrefix="{culture}/testarea"]` <-- specific culture